# React Native: How do you add PanResponder to a Touchable element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make a button that you can drag. I realize that I can simulate `onPress` events with `onPanResponderRelease`, but it doesn't work on some Android devices.

When I try wrapping a Touchable element with an `Animated.View` with `panHandlers`, the pan responder gets touch priority and the Touchable element's `onPress` prop doesn't get called. Is there a way to have both the Touchable element's `onPress` function and `PanResponder` config methods get called simultaneously?